# CakePHP Rest Plugin Question

Tags: php, cakephp, rest, plugins, http-headers

I am new to REST. I understand how to create the functions within the application. BUT I am not sure how to access the JSON request using REST with headers. I am using CakePHP as my framework and in addition to that I am using the CakePHP REST plugin by KVZ (https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin). I am using ACL within my application and therefore I need to login using REST headers or however you access that information. I am pretty sure your suppose to use the amazon S3 authentication method but I don't understand it. I haven't been able to find any clear information on this.

THE QUESTION: How do I access the function (http://localhost:5555/app/data/getAll.json) using a REST JSON Request with PHP? Please include how to send the username and password with HTTP_AUTHORIZATION/header. The more detailed the answered, the better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

REST isn't a technology, its just a way of naming your urls.  Have a look at http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html.  You can use any mechanism you like to access the page although Curl with PHP is probably the easiest way for you.

Have a look at the [PHP curl docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), there are examples there to guide you.

Comment: That clarifies some stuff. Thanks. I am just mostly confused on how to do use the CakePHP Rest plugin.